# Optimal way to set Python regex flags using user defined boolean values

Tags: python, regex

I am building a regex checking tool using python, where the user creates the pattern, checks the flags he/she needs, and then tests different strings using the generated pattern. Python has 6 regex flags: re.I, re.M, re.S, re.U, re.L, and re.X, so writing an if-else statement would be a nightmare, thanks to all the combinations.

Is there a way to define the flags as just boolean values instead? Something like this:

`re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE=ignorecase, re.MULTILINE=multiline, ...)`

The above code does not work, but hopefully it makes it clear. The `pattern`, `ignorecase`, and `multiline` are all variables defined by the user using a simple form containing an input for the patter, and checkboxes for the flags.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You *could* easily write a function that converts a list of 6 booleans to any combination of regex flags. However I think I didn't understand what you are trying to do and what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Yes, and correct me if I am wrong because math isn't my strong suit, but wouldn't that take a huge number of if-else statements?

Comment: I think it would take exactly 6 if statements.

Comment: If the user is restricted to input the correct alphabet letters for modifiers, then you can just construct a regex with inline modifiers. Example `"(?"+user letters+")(?:"+user regex+")". Then you don't have to worry about passing in flags. It's just a one liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a convenient way to combine enabled flags into a single argument that you can pass. Instead of setting a different value for each flag, I would advise simply checking what is set (in whatever way you already do this), and immediately merging the corresponding flag into a single accumulator variable.

For example, supposing the flags were specified as command line arguments I might do it like this:

```
userchoices = 0
if "-a" in opts:
    userchoices |= re.A
if "-i" in opts:
    userchoices |= re.I
if "-L" in opts:
    userchoices |= re.L
etc.

matcher = re.compile(pattern, flags=userchoices)
```

If you have already written the code that initializes each of your named variables to the corresponding `re.?` constant, you can simply collect them into an array and OR them together like this:

```
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce
userchoices = reduce(or_, [asciionly, ignorecase, multiline, ...])
```

Depending on how you detect the user's selections, you could streamline this further by e.g. using a dictionary to map the options of your form to python constants, etc.

PS. An alternative approach: each flag can be expressed by the corresponding letter and embedded in the regexp itself. So you could do something like this, and bypass the `flags` argument altogether:

```
userflags = "".join([asciionly, ignorecase, multiline, ...])
matcher = re.compile("(?%s)%s" % (userflags, pattern) )
```

I think this is kind of hacky, to be honest, but there may be a place for it since the regexp encapsulates the settings it is being used with.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I thought the flags would have to be combined using bitwise OR.

Comment: Oops, you are right! I was thinking of the flags you embed in a regexp... but still managed to use the `flags` argument in the snippet :-( ... Hold on, revision coming

Comment: Now it matches what the OP wants...